# Regarding blackboard bold version of \mu in RevTex

Tags: greek, revtex, blackboard

```
\documentclass[reprint,aps]{revtex4-1}

\usepackage{graphicx} % for pdf, bitmapped graphics files
\usepackage{graphics}
\usepackage{epsfig} % for postscript graphics files
\usepackage{mathptmx} % assumes new font selection scheme installed
\usepackage{times} % assumes new font selection scheme installed
\usepackage[bbgreekl]{mathbbol}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsfonts} % assumes amsmath package installed
\usepackage{colortbl}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{epstopdf}

\usepackage{arydshln}
\usepackage{bm}
\usepackage{relsize}

\usepackage{graphicx}% Include figure files
\usepackage{dcolumn}% Align table columns on decimal point
\usepackage{bm}% bold math

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\DeclareSymbolFontAlphabet{\mathbb}{AMSb}
\DeclareSymbolFontAlphabet{\mathbbl}{bbold}
```

Hi, I am using RevTex and while I need the blackboard bold version of lowercase \mu. I have tried out some different approaches and this seems to be the only one working. However, this does not print a good-looking mu. Any suggestions?

```
\begin{document}

\begin{equation}\label{eq:Ltilde_offdiagonal}
\widetilde{\mathbf{L}}(i,j)=\mathbb{M}_{0,k}+\bbmu_{(0,k)}^{(k,i)}+\bbmu_{(0,k)}^{(k,j)}+\bbmu_{(k,i)}^{(k,j)}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

[image: Here is what it looks like ...]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Which appearance would you prefer?

Comment: Something like this

Comment: ![][2]
  [2]: http://i.stack.imgur.com/E9QBP.png